# Fix for when table is extending past navbar and footer

Tags: html, css

My table is expanding past the width of my navbar and footer. Using HTML and/or CSS, how would I make it so the width of my navbar and footer expand out to match the width of my table. Is this possible? All the solutions I have come across involve formatting the table rather than formatting the navbar and footer

The problem with that is it crams all the fields within the browser view, so things get jumbled up.  Any help here would be appreciated.

[image]

Code:

```css
        html,
        body {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         width: 100%
        }
    
        body {
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
         justify-content: space-between;
        }
    
        main {
         flex: 1;
        }
    
        .footer {
         background-color: #003366;
         text-align: center;
         color: white;
         height: 30px;
        }
    
        #footer-center {
         color: white;
        }
    
        #footer-right {
         float: right;
         color: blue;
        }
        
        nav .navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark {
            width: 100%
        }
    
        .navbar-nav li:hover>.dropdown-menu {
         display: block;
         content: none;
        }
    
        .dropdown-menu.show {
         background-color: #f5f6f7;
        }
    
        table.GeneratedTable {
          background-color: #ffffff;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border-width: 2px;
          border-color: #ffcc00;
          border-style: solid;
          color: #000000;
        /*table-layout: fixed;        ---I've tried this
          width: 100%;*/
      }
    
        table.GeneratedTable td, table.GeneratedTable th {
          border-color: #ffcc00;
          border-style: solid;
        }
    
        table.GeneratedTable thead {
          background-color: #ffcc00;
        }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
        <title>Album example for Bootstrap</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" height="30" width="30" class="d-inline-block align-top"> Website</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">NavItem</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">NavItem</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    
        <main class='wrapper'>
            <br>
            <br>
            <table class="GeneratedTable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                  <td>Cell</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </main>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="footer-center">Copyright © Company Name {% now "Y" %}
                    <div id="footer-right"><a href="#" class="text-muted">Back to top</a></div>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can. ( maybe with some javaScript ) . Because the table width is overflowing the page. The others ( nav/footer ) are already at 100% width of the page. If you would know the width of the table you could do that. But that width i guess is not always the same so you need some javaScript.

Comment: I'm not well versed with JavaScript. Is it a simple fix with the JS?

Comment: Well. Yes. It's simple. You just need to 'get' the width of the table and give it to the nav and the footer. The solutions with css involve setting footer/nav fixed which mean they do not increase in size but instead move left/right with your horizontal scroll

Comment: I made an answer below using javaScript

Comment: I personally think Javsacript is o̶v̶e̶r̶k̶i̶l̶l̶ unnecessary for this. Why flex the page to fit the table when you can make the page stationary and scroll the table with css? Flexing the header/footer will mean inconsistent spacing between nav/menu items, logos, or other elements within.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way for you to do it is have the footer and menu as `position: fixed`. This means that no matter where you scroll on the page these objects will remain in the same place.

I have done it with your footer below:

```
.footer {
    background-color: #003366;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

The nav bar would work in a similar way but you would need to target the `header` tag:

```
header {
    background-color: #003366;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Also, to change where the table sits on the page you can use `margin-top`, this can be set to `%` or `px`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The footer works perfectly. Navbar has some issues though. I had to use `header` in the css, targeting the navbar wouldnt work for me. Once I targeted the `header` element, the navbar did expand but the table slid up to the navbar. Why would my table be moving up like that? Maybe there is a fix for this too?

Comment: @NickT Just made some edits. Let me know if this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple example using javaScript. I tried to make it as close as possible to your specific situation.

You just need to get the width of the table and set it to the header/footer or other elements you need

```js
(function() {
  const header = document.querySelector('header')
  const footer = document.querySelector('.footer')
  const tableWidth = document.querySelector('.GeneratedTable').offsetWidth
  header.style.width = `${tableWidth}px`
  footer.style.width = `${tableWidth}px`
})();
```

```css
table {
  width: 3000px;
  background: black;
}

header {
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}

footer {
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<table class="GeneratedTable">
  <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

Comment: If I need to specify the width of this table, that probably means my other tables (similar to this one) on other pages will need to be specified as well, correct?

Comment: @NickT No, you don't have to specify in CSS the width of the table. I did that only for example purposes. You can leave your CSS exactly how it is. Just add the JavaScript code

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back. So I copied it and pasted just your JS code between two <script> tags right before my closing <head> tag. It didnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you had a follow up to this. I really would like to get this to work!

Comment: @NickT try wrapping all the js code in a self-invoking function `(function() { code here })();` i edited the answer with this

Answer (score 0):

Since your table is contained in an element with the `.wrapper` class, you could add `overflow: auto` to this div. It's not ideal, as the table will still be wider than the page, but it means that the table scrolls rather than the page itself.

Expand the snippet to full-size to see the result.

```html
<html>
<head>

    <style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    main {
        flex: 1;
    }

    .footer {
        background-color: #003366;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        height: 30px;
    }

    #footer-center {
        color: white;
    }

    #footer-right {
        float: right;
        color: blue;
    }

    nav .navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark {
        width: 100%
    }

    .navbar-nav li:hover>.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        content: none;
    }

    .dropdown-menu.show {
        background-color: #f5f6f7;
    }
    
    .wrapper{
      overflow: auto;
    }

    table.GeneratedTable {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-width: 2px;
      border-color: #ffcc00;
      border-style: solid;
      color: #000000;
  }

    table.GeneratedTable td, table.GeneratedTable th {
      border-color: #ffcc00;
      border-style: solid;
    }

    table.GeneratedTable thead {
      background-color: #ffcc00;
    }
    </style>

    {% load staticfiles %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Album example for Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                <img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" height="30" width="30" class="d-inline-block align-top"> Website</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">NavItem</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">NavItem</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main class='wrapper'>
        <br>
        <br>
        <table class="GeneratedTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
              <td>Cell</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </main>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="footer-center">Copyright © Company Name {% now "Y" %}
                <div id="footer-right"><a href="#" class="text-muted">Back to top</a></div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

letting the table having horizontal scroll , if mobile first is a priority ,rest of the page can be styles normally

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code is more or less a duplicate to @lewis's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55142461/7451109).